# Is there any option to permanently store a data in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

We have hadoop DB with one namenode and four datanode here. Once we store a file or script in master its not stored for more than one day. When we shutdown a DB its totally corrupted. How to overcome it?

Comment: HDFS data will not be deleted. you should have basic knowledge on Hadoop. Start from [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you delete the directory defined by parameter ${hdfs.data.dir}

Comment: If you accept my answer, please adopt it to help my reputation.Thanks.